# Random Forest Techniques/Models

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, random-forest, machine-learning-model, self-study

Can anyone tell about different Techniques/algorithms of Random forest?
I know, Random Forest is itself an algorithm/model, but I'm looking for another version of it as we have in decision trees.
List of Algorithms based on Random Forest?
Thanks

Comment: You might be interested in gradient boosting methods, such as XGBoost or LightGBM

Answer (score 1):

Random Forest is a tree based ensemble algorithm which uses bagging to improve the performance of the algorithm. There are few improved/modified Random Forest algorithms which includes weighted quadratic random forest and weighted class random forest, to name a few. These algorithms are not mainstream algorithms and can be used for very specific purposes - imbalanced target labels.

If you are looking for tree based algorithms, look at GBM, LightGBM, XGB and CatBoost.

Answer (score 0):

Random Forest is a very specific technique, is itself a variation of other techniques.

In this link you will find a list of techniques related to random forest:

[Forest of randomized trees](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html#forests-of-randomized-trees)